# Setting background color of root window

Tags: background, xlib

I am trying to learn XLib. And I searched throught source of Feh program to understand how to modify root window, but I had no results.

There is code to test root window access, but I don't understand why it is not working.

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

Display *disp2;
Window root2;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{

 disp2 = XOpenDisplay(NULL); 
 root2 = RootWindow(disp2, DefaultScreen(disp2));
 // Generation of random number to set window color
 srand(time(NULL));
 int i = rand();
 // Setting background
 // I forgot to change 256 to i
 // XSetWindowBackground(disp2, root2, 256 );
 XSetWindowBackground(disp2, root2, i
 XClearWindow(disp2, root2);
 // Showing the random number
 printf ("%i \n", i );

 return 0;

}
```

So, what's wrong in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in the code. You're just trying to print random number. If you need to print random number fro.m 0-256 then try

```
int i = rand()%256;
```

you can change color of root window in command line
[Check this out](http://www.dsl.org/cookbook/cookbook_6.html#SEC94)!

What is your exact problem.
Your question lacks context.

Comment: I am trying to change background color to understand the process. I am already seen Xsetroot and other software.

But I want simple code to do this. My goal is to experiment with animated desktop backgrounds via pixmaps after understanding that.